# Retrieve multiple information in a group by

Tags: sql

I have a table 'purchases' with 3 columns Serviceid, Date, User_id

Some data looks like this:

```
20  2-Jan-18    40709217
20  2-Jan-18    40709217
40  2-Jan-18    40709217
40  2-Jan-20    40709217
50  2-Jan-21    40709217    
984 22-Mar-18   18246539    
269 22-Mar-18   18246539    
666 1-Apr-18    18246539
```

My query request is:

For each 'user_id', get these information:

- First 2 earliest ServiceId and Date that user purchased
- The lastest ServiceId and Date that user purchased
- Count of services that user purchased

Result table's column must follow this order:
User_id, FirstServiceid, SecondServiceid, FirstServiceDate, SecondServiceDate, LastServiceid, LastServiceDate, TotalService.

Expected output:

| User_id | FirstServiceid | SecondServiceid | FirstDate | SecondDate | LastServiceid | LastDate | TotalServices |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 40709217 | 20 | 40 | 2-Jan-18 | 2-Jan-20 | 50 | 2-Jan-21 | 5 |
| 18246539 | 984 | 666 | 22-Mar-18 | 1-Apr-18 | 666 | 1-Apr-18 | 3 |

My idea was to do aggregations, then join them together but I ran into this error

> "Column 'purchase.Serviceid' is invalid in the select list because it
> is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
> clause"

when calling the lastest Serviceid and Date:

```
select user_id, max(date), serviceid    
from purchases    
group by user_id
```

How to overcome this and is there a better way to aggregate lots of information without having to use JOIN?

Comment: Can you add the expected output values from the input values in your example?

Comment: Why SecondServiceid is 40 instead of 20? Do you want distinct SecondServiceid?

Comment: Which database management system (eg mysql/sqlserver/postgres etc) and what version are you using?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai Because the second date that user 40709217 purchased something was 2-Jan-20 and that something is Serviceid 40!

Comment: @ggordon microsoft sql. I used sqliteonline.com for testing so Idk about the version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using the following which uses window functions such as `row_number` and `dense_rank` to identify desired records before aggregating your results by `user_id` and using a case expression within the `MAX` function to extract the data in the desired columns

```sql
SELECT
    User_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN earliest_order=1 and rp=1 THEN Serviceid END) as FirstServiceid,
    MAX(CASE WHEN earliest_order=2 and rp=1 THEN Serviceid END) as SecondServiceid,
    MAX(CASE WHEN earliest_order=1 and rp=1 THEN [Date] END) as FirstServiceDate,
    MAX(CASE WHEN earliest_order=2 and rp=1 THEN [Date] END) as SecondServiceDate,
    MAX(CASE WHEN latest_order=1 THEN Serviceid END) as LastServiceid,
    MAX(CASE WHEN latest_order=1 THEN [Date] END) as LastServiceDate,
    COUNT(1) as TotalService
FROM (
   SELECT 
       *,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (
           PARTITION BY User_id
           ORDER BY [Date] 
       ) as earliest_order,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY User_id
           ORDER BY [Date] DESC, Serviceid
       ) as latest_order,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
              PARTITION BY User_id,[Date]
              ORDER BY Serviceid DESC
       ) rp
   FROM 
       purchases
   
) t
GROUP BY
    User_id
ORDER BY
    User_id DESC
```

The results of the subquery used above have been included below also for your perusal.

```sql
   SELECT
        *,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (
           PARTITION BY User_id
           ORDER BY [Date] 
       ) as earliest_order,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY User_id
           ORDER BY [Date] DESC, Serviceid
       ) as latest_order,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
              PARTITION BY User_id,[Date]
              ORDER BY Serviceid DESC
       ) rank_priority
   FROM
           purchases
    ORDER BY User_id, [Date], Serviceid DESC
```

| Serviceid | Date | User_id | earliest_order | latest_order | rank_priority |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 984 | 2018-03-22 | 18246539 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 269 | 2018-03-22 | 18246539 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 666 | 2018-04-01 | 18246539 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 40 | 2018-01-02 | 40709217 | 1 | 5 | 1 |
| 20 | 2018-01-02 | 40709217 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 20 | 2018-01-02 | 40709217 | 1 | 4 | 3 |
| 40 | 2020-01-02 | 40709217 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 50 | 2021-01-02 | 40709217 | 3 | 1 | 1 |

[View working demo db fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e4f833d6e75654c799fe02d810f013cc)

Comment: That's a lot to cover for someone new to SQL like me. Thank you!